# Disabling line in Select by expression dialog of QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I would like to disable some lines in the 'Select by expression' dialog (QGIS 2.6) but I can't find whether it is possible or not, and if yes, how to achieve that.

I have tried several characters such as /, //, /*, #, REM.

Note that `/*` and `REM` transform the line into green text, which seems to be disabled, but the query result is empty and I get in invalid expression error below the query field.

Comment: I don't think the 'commenting-out' feature is fully implmented even though it may visually look like it is. Hopefully others can confirm this as I have not looked at the source code.

Answer (score 1):

Not in 2.6 but in 2.8 comments have been implemented as a new feature in expressions.

Comment: Goog thing indeed! Is v2.8 expected soon? Nothing about that on official QGIS website.